# Button packed in a python 3.6 Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

im actually scratching my head really bad, i'm suck on a simple thing, i want to pack a button in a tkinter frame, but the problem is that i only see the frame when i dont pack the button in it if i pack the button in it i only see the button...

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root,bg ='yellow')
frame.pack()

bottomframe = Frame(root,bg = 'red')
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

redbutton = Button(frame, text = "Red", fg = "red")
redbutton.pack( side = LEFT)

blackbutton = Button(bottomframe, text = "Black", fg = "black")
blackbutton.pack( side = BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

this is correctly displaying my two buttons but not the frames, i know it because i dont see the colors, i must be doing something stupid and wrong or not i dont know, anyway help would be appreciated , thanks and keep on coding !

Comment: why are you creating a frame? Just use `root.configure(bg='yellow')`

Comment: i want to have a frame for a specific reason, i'll have a few frames that are not containing the same things that's why

Comment: What happens is that blackbutton is replacing in position to frame. Could you tell us how you want the distribution of the elements?

Comment: well i want to have like buttons that never change during the whole execution of my programs and they will be in one frame , others will be in another frame because they will be generated by the script and be refreshed at some ponts :)

Answer (score 0):

Frames (actually, all widgets) are designed to shrink or expand to fit their contents. If a frame has no children it remains the configured size, but if you add children it will shrink or grow to fit unless it is constrained by its parent.

Assuming you want `frame` to take up most of the space, and `bottomframe` to be a strip of buttons along the bottom, you need to provide proper arguments to `pack` to make that happen.

For example:

```
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM, fill="x")
```

`fill` is used to control how the widget fits in the space given to it. By setting the value to "both", it instructs tkinter to have the frame fill its parent in both the x and y directions. Using a value of "x" means it is to fill its space in the "x" direction only.

`expand` is used to control how extra space is allocated. When set to `True`, it instructs this widget to expand to fill any leftover space in its parent. When set to `False` it won't consume any extra space.

When using `pack`, you typically will have one widget that has `expand` set to `True`, though two is often common if you want to divide the parent in half.

Comment: i have this kind of thing but in separate code and i have a frame set with a width and height , isn't it enought ? :/

Comment: @Prosity: Setting a width and height is not enough. Like I said in my answer, a frame will grow or shrink to fit its contents. Generally speaking you should never need to give explicit widths and heights to a frame.

Comment: ok so how can i make my frame sort of 'locked' or set to a specific size ? is it possible ? or maybe there is another widget that can achieve this ? thanks :)

Comment: and apparently expand is unknown in python 3.6 i got an error :/

Comment: ok wasn't using it the right way, but is it possible to lock the size of the frame ? :)

Comment: @Prosity: why do you want to "lock" the size of the frame? Why not take the time to design your UI so that it properly grows and shrinks? A fixed-size GUI is rarely the best solution. If you do a little research you'll find several answers to your question.

Comment: thank you very much, with you mentioning it it looks a better option , thank you very much for all your answers ! :-)